# image not showing on datatable and showing 404 not found when opened

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-404

```
{
    name: 'file',
    data: 'file',
    "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
        return "<img src=\"/public/storage/"+data+"\" height=\"50\"/>";   
    },
    "title": "identity",
    "orderable": true,
    "searchable": true,
},
```

My sql database store the image name and a function send the image to the `public/storage` folder, the idea is when the image is clicked it show the image. but instead it show 404 not found page, http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/storage/1669581019license.jpg = the address bar.
file name is the same, no difference at all. please help my deadline is in a few hours.

i tried using the `php artisan storage:link` command and i also tried to change the directory. nothing happened

Comment: `/public/storage/`? The folder `public` should _not_ appear in any Laravel url - it should be the "DocumentRoot" of your project/vhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Ricky Ferdinand,

Hope you are doing well and good.

Replace your render code to below,

```
"render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    return '<img src="' + data + '" alt="' + data + '"height="16" width="16"/>';
                }
```

Comment: It worked like a charm, thank you brother. I just changed it to your code and remove the public folder from the code and its running now!